# Understanding scikit neural network parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, scikit-image

I've been trying to train a neural network to recognise the three types of tags I have images of (circle, rectangle and blank). I used the example set up for recognising the digits dataset provided [here](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/master/examples/plot_digits.py) and found that I got a 75% correct prediction rate with barely any tweaking (provided my images had a certain level of preprocessing with filters etc).

What I'm interested in understanding more about is the classifier section (code below). I'm not sure what the different convolution and layer options do and what options I have for tweaking them. Does anyone have any advice for other convolution or layers that I could use to try improve my prediction accuracy and what they mean? Apologies for being vague, this is the first time I've touched a NN and am struggling to get my head around it.

```
nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
        Convolution('Rectifier', channels=12, kernel_shape=(3, 3), border_mode='full'),
        Convolution('Rectifier', channels=8, kernel_shape=(3, 3), border_mode='valid'),
        Layer('Rectifier', units=64),
        Layer('Softmax')],
    learning_rate=0.002,
    valid_size=0.2,
    n_stable=10,
    verbose=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend the excellent [video course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH) by Hugo Larochelle on Youtube. [The 9th chapter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxKrCa4bg1I&index=69&list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH) is about convolutional networks and explains all the parameters. You might start from the first two chapters, they explain how the neural networks work in general, and you will get used to the terms like `softmax` and `rectifier`.

Another good resource: [Andrej Karpathy's lecture notes](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check them out :)

Comment: @Hrant Khachatrian +1 for those great lecture notes! Quite interesting resources.